# Output to a plain text file with Go programming language?

Tags: go, text, file-io, io, output

So I'm trying to get my little program to output to a plain text file. I've been successful with Python, C, C++ and C#, but I can't seem to find any documentation on outputting data to a plain text file with Go. Here's my code:

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func main() {
    var age string
    fmt.Print("\nWelcome to Survey! What is your age?\n\n")
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &age)
      if _, err := strconv.ParseInt(age,10,64); err == nil  {
          fmt.Printf("\nYou are %s years old!\n", age)
        } else {
        fmt.Printf("\nThat's not an age! Try again... \n")
      }
    fmt.Println("\nNice! Now, what is your name?\n")
    fmt.Printf("Enter your name: ")
    var name string
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &name)
    fmt.Println("\nHello " + name + "! It's nice to meet you!")
    fmt.Println("\nWould you like to write your age and name to a text file?")
    fmt.Println("\nPress 1 for yes or any other key for no!\n")
    var yes int
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &yes)
    if yes == 1 {
      fmt.Printf("\nAll done! Check Survey.txt in the current directory!\n")
    } else {
      fmt.Printf("\nOkay! Exiting... \n\n")
    }
}
```

You can see if the user enters 1, it prints a message to check the current directory for Survey.txt. Basically all I'm trying to do is have Go write the age and name variables to a plain text file called Survey.txt.

Example:

```
Age: x
Name: x
```

If anyone has an idea of how to do this, it'd be awesome. My operating system is Xubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, but I don't think that will have much of an impact. The code works fine as is right now, I just want to add that feature. Thanks!

Comment: On your question hover the mouse atop the tag for go which appears two inches above this comment ..  then click on info to see TONS of documentation on golang with tuts taboot - Welcome to SO ... critical skill of a great developer is ability to become self sufficient and read the docs ... bonus points for reading the spec of whichever language

Answer (score 4):

You can write to a file using [ioutil.WriteFile](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#WriteFile):

```
data := fmt.Sprintf("Age: %d\nName: %s\n", age, name)

err := ioutil.WriteFile("Survey.txt", []byte(data), 0644)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error writing Survey.txt: %s", err)
}
```

Comment: This looks super useful! Thank you, I'm going to give it a try! :)

Answer (score -1):

I think it's easy to output to a text file. Simply redirect the program output. On the terminal command line 
goprogram >> outputFile.txt
Anyway, I am only providing a suggestion, you don't have to click minuses, given that no explanation is provided if that is urgent, if it's for academia etc.

Comment: I could do it that way, but I don't want to rely on the terminal/BASH to output to a file. I'd rather have Go do it from within the program.